# Which metric is the main one in a metric-affine theory? $g^{\mu\nu}$ or its conformal counterpart?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, modified-gravity

For a [metric-affine theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric-affine_gravitation_theory), I have found a conformal metric as
$$h_{\mu\nu}=f(R)~g_{\mu\nu}.$$
My question is which metric is more important? For example in finding the weak field limit of such a theory, one can find two potentials by using these two metrics. I mean $\Phi_1=-(1/2) ~ g_{00}$ and $\Phi_2=-(1/2)~h_{00}$. Is the conformal metric only an instrument to solve the problem or contains a meaningful physics too?

In other words, which metric can be considered as the main metric that determines the physical properties of the problem.

Comment: Dear @Qmechanic, Did U ban me?! How can I ask the question?

Comment: No. [Q&A bans](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5951/2451) are caused by an [automated SE script](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8851/2451). Moderators can't hand out Q&A bans. In the future, after the ban lifts, be very careful to only ask questions that will be positively received.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Actually it is the second time:/ What should I do? My questions were not bad!

Answer (score 2):

The [Jordan frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_and_Einstein_frames) $g_{\mu\nu}$ is minimally coupled to matter while the [Einstein frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_and_Einstein_frames) $h_{\mu\nu}$ is minimally coupled to the Ricci curvature tensor. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_and_Einstein_frames) (June, 2018) writes that *"there is currently heated debate about whether either, both, or neither frame is a 'physical' frame which can be compared to observations and experiment".*